# How come my Javascript is not updating time correctly?

Tags: javascript, time, setinterval, clock

Okay, I'm having the strangest issue. I created a code based off of one that I found on codepen. It works perfectly in Codepen changing the image every hour. I tested it by changing my clock. However, when uploaded on my website it does not update correctly.

Here is my local html:

```
 <div class="table">    
    <div id="plate">
    <div id="hour1"> </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

css:

```
html,body { margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color : #fff; }

#plate{
width: 465px;
height: 465px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image:url(http://www.cassietodd.me/gra423/clockapp/images/Pieclock_plate.png);
}

#hour1{
float:left;
width: 320px;
height: 520px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(http://www.cassietodd.me/gra423/clockapp/images/strawberry_01.png);
background-size: 104%;
}

.table{
margin: 0px auto;
margin-top: 30px;
width:320px;
height: 568px;  
background-image: url(http://www.cassietodd.me/gra423/clockapp/images/Pieclock_table.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

my javascript:

```
 window.onload = function () {
  var updateView = (function() {
  var sec;
  return function () {
   var now = new Date();
   if (now.getSeconds() == sec) return;

var second = now.getSeconds();
var minute = now.getMinutes();
var hour = now.getHours();


var hour1;
if(hour < 12){
  hour1 = 0;
}else{
  hour1 = Math.floor(hour / 2);
}
var hour1 = hour%12;

  _updateView(hour1);
}
 })();

setInterval(updateView, 500);

function _updateView(h1) {

var _url = "http://www.cassietodd.me/gra423/clockapp/images/";
 $('#hour1').css("background-image", "url("+_url+"h" + h1 + ".png)");
 }
}
```

You can see the one that works on Codepen.
http://codepen.io/cmtodd3/pen/mzibu

Its the exact same code but it works on codepen but on my website the time is all wrong? Here is my test website just in case

http://www.cassietodd.me/gra423/clockapp

Comment: FYI 1 hours is one slice. So if one slice is missing its 1:00

Answer (score 0):

I got the code to work user error. I just needed to open a new window. I'd been using the same window for the last hour as soon as I closed it and opened my site again it was working. I'm not sure why that happened but I'm answering my own question. Oops I'm embarrassed.